# How to use unison to sync files in ext4 filesystem with FAT filesystem? (permission bit)

Tags: linux, bash, unison

My machine is linux ext4. I have an external hard drive with FAT. I can syn most of the files without any problem. However, there is always a few files having permission problems.

I tried to use unison -fat to specify the sync policy. However, unison does not seem to take my command. Here is what I tried:

My profile.pcf specify the path: (from home to media)

```
root = /home/allen/allen
root = /media/portable/allen
```

Then I type this:

```
unison work -fat perm=0
```

In both of the commands, unison treats work as a directory rather than a profile. Please give some hints.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to use a profile `work` you must create a file `~/.unison/work.prf`. According to the [documentation](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#prefs) you just have to add a line `fat = true` to the profile in order to make synchronization with FAT file systems work.

Comment: Yes. The profile is there. Command "unison work" works fine. But I dont know how to add -fat policy.

Comment: If I read the [documentation](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#prefs) correctly, all you need to do is add a line `fat = true` to the profile.

Comment: Yes. This solves the problem. Could you please add this line to the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Many FAT partitions get mounted under /media by default, so unison may requires write access there for temp files as well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).